# Redis range lookup query for latitude and longitude without radius

Tags: redis, reverse-geocoding

We are trying to do a reverse geo lookup using redis

The meta data has been loaded inside redis in the following manner

```
> geoadd cities lon lat citycode
```

The intention is to find out the nearest city that is in the range of latitude and longitude provided as input (radius unknown)

e.g

```
geoadd cities 74.0059 40.7128 NewYork
```

If the following inputs are provided the system should return the city code for NewYork e.g NewYork

- 73.9857,40.7484
- 74.0445,40.6892
- 73.9851,40.7589

Redis unfortunately requires you to specify the radius due to which unless a radius is provided it does not reverse map to a city correctly.

I am looking for solution specific to redis and I am aware that this can be done quite easily with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You **CANNOT** do that with Redis, since it only gives limited supports for GEO operations.

You need other databases to do this kind of query, such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) or [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/)